# Regex replace multiple groups with wildcards

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I found an answer when we do not use wildcard characters. So question is - how to perform multiple replaces by regex. This code shows what i want to do

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rules = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {@"F\S+", "Replace 1"},
                        {@"\S+z", "Replace 2"},
                    };

        string s = "Foo bar baz";
        string result = ProcessText(s, rules);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private static string ProcessText(string input, Dictionary<string, string> rules)
    {
        string[] patterns = rules.Keys.ToArray();
        string pattern = string.Join("|", patterns);
        return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match =>
                                             {
                                                 int index = GetMatchIndex(match);
                                                 return rules[patterns[index]];
                                             });
    }

    private static int GetMatchIndex(Match match)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Match g in match.Groups)
        {
            if (g.Success)
                return i;
            i++;
        }
        throw new Exception("Never throws");
    }
}
```

but `match.Groups.Count` is always 1.

I'm looking for the fastest alternative. Perhaps, it shouldn't use regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why are you concatenating patterns and then performin so many searches in an array.

Can't you just apply each pattern individually like this?

```
var rules = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {@"F\S+", "Replace 1"},
                    {@"\S+z", "Replace 2"},
                };

string s = "Foo bar baz";
var result = rules.Aggregate(s, (seed, rule) => Regex.Replace(seed, rule.Key, m => rule.Value));
```

**EDIT**

Your `match.Groups.Count` is always one because there are no groups defined in your matches and the values is the entire matched string as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx). In other words, your `GetMatchIndex` method does nothing.

You could try transforming your patterns into named groups like this:

```
var patterns = rules.Select((kvp, index) => new 
{
    Key = String.Format("(?<{0}>{1})", index, kvp.Key),
    Value = kvp.Value
};
```

Having this array, in `GetMatchIndex` method you'd just parse the group name as being the index of the matched pattern:

```
private static int GetMatchIndex(Regex regex, Match match)
{
    foreach(var name in regex.GetGroupNames())
    {
        var group = match.Groups[name];
        if(group.Success)
            return int.Parse(name); //group name is a number
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
var pattern = String.Join("|", patterns.Select(x => x.Key));
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
return regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => 
{
    var index = GetMatchIndex(regex, m);
    return patterns[index].Value;
});
```

Comment: Suppose that Dictionary has 50000 items. In this case we have 50k `Regex.Replace` calls when I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

To make it (probably way) faster extract

```
var keyArray = rules.Keys.ToArray()
```

before you use it in:

```
return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match =>
{
    int index = GetMatchIndex(match);
    return rules[keyArray[index]];
});
```

Comment: Sorry, resharper inlined my temp variable. Tnx for answer, posted original code instead of this 'optimized'